# Client.GetAsync returns null

Tags: c#, async-await, xamarin.forms

I can't figure out why my await client.GetAsync is returning null when trying to get data from my web api controller. I hit the controller method successfully, but afterwards my mobile PCL method exits from my client.GetAsync line. Am I missing something? Here is my mobile method:

```
public async void onLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = BaseUrl + "/loginapi/login?username=" + eUserName.Text + "&password=" + ePassword.Text;

        var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

        var jsonResponse = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (client)
            {
                var getDataResponse = await client.GetAsync("", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

                //If we do not get a successful status code, then return an empty set
                if (!getDataResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    jsonResponse = null;

                //Retrieve the JSON response
                jsonResponse = await getDataResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (jsonResponse != null)
                {
                    //map object

                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new CalendarView());
                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: The fact that it exits from your controller method as soon as it hits that line is to be expected, since you're awaiting an asynchronous operation. Control will be returned to the method once the task returned by `onLoginClicked` is awaited. Are you sure the return value is null and not a failed HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint at `If we do not get a successful ...`, to see what the value of `getDataResponse` is.

Comment: If I step through it, getDataResponse is null when my break is at the last bracket. Would this be caused by web api not getting back with data before that point?

Comment: Actually after following your advice and placing a breakpoint on the if statement, I'm getting the data. Not sure why it was exiting the method with the breakpoint on the await client.GetAsync line. Thanks for your suggestion, you can post as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `async void` (see the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx article for a more thorough explanation - especially around the exception semantics).

My suggestion is to change your method signature to the following:

```
public async Task onLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You will then be able to wrap your await statement in a try/catch to look for any exceptions been thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "Copy Local" property of the System.Net.Http reference of your PCL class to false, and adding the System.Net.Http reference to both your android and iOS project. 
Apparently the System.Net.Http reference behaves unexpectedly in PCLs. There is more information on this thread.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7719/using-httpclient